# How to re-sample pandas data-frame containing categorical data?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a data frame with columns:
 - Machine:[Machine1, Machine2, Machine3, Machine4, Machine5, Machine6]
 - Time: Datetime 27102016 00:00:00 - 00:59:00 (every minutes)
 - OutX: Integer
 - OutY: Integer

The dataframe contains readings for OutX and OutY for all Machines for all minutes under the time range in the time column.

```
yeild = pd.read_csv("d:/xdata/question.csv",parse_dates=True, index_col='Time')
yeild.dtypes
```

Machine    object
OutX        int64
OutY        int64
dtype: object

```
yeild.describe()
```

...........OutX OutY
count   358.000000  358.000000
mean    69.782123   70.715084
std 9.685677    12.451468
min 64.000000   66.000000
25% 67.000000   68.000000
50% 68.000000   69.000000
75% 70.000000   70.000000
max 202.000000  246.000000

I want to resample the data so that Maximum values of OutX and OutY can be observed in the resampled dataframe (let's call it sample).

```
sample = yeild.resample('10t').max()
```

I only get six records after sampling, because it is only accepting the max values for all OutX and OutY.
How can I resample keeping the different categorical values ( Machine1, Machine2 ... Machine6) keeping intact? i.e, get the max of OutX and OutY in every 10 minutes for all machines under consideration.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

***this is unverified because you didn't provide any sample data and I didn't feel like making up data... I hope it works***

you want to know *where* the `max` is and slice `yield` with those locations.  You can find out *where* with `idxmax`

```
# where OutX is max within each 10 minutes
mxX = yeild.resample('10t').OutX.idxmax()
# where OutY is max within each 10 minutes
mxY = yeild.resample('10t').OutY.idxmax()
# union of mxX and mxY
idx = mxX.append(mxY, ignore_index=True).unique()

# slice yeild (sic) with locations of where
# either OutY or OutX is max
sample = yeild.loc[idx]
```